# How are defunct networks removed from a LogMeIn Hamachi network?

Tags: networking, hamachi

I have a Hamachi network that I use for work and one that I use with friends.

For the one that I use w/ friends, I'm the administrator of the network. Occasionally I have to reset my system from time to time, and have used the "ditch the old network and make a new one for all" strategy when I forget to delete my Hamachi network.

Is there a way to remove obsolete "machines" from a main Hamachi network? I did some research on Google throughout the Hamachi forums where there are quite a few requests about this, but all of which respond with a situation of bewilderment from people in the same situation who want to know.

A good bit of the methods that are proposed to actually work are for Windows machines only and involve quite a lot of file tinkering. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: So you're asking how to kill an entire network after you've accidentally left the network as the only admin?  I use LogMeIn Central and administer all my networks from there (including destroying a network)

Comment: Going through LogMeIn Central is just more headache; they just keep pressing LogMeIn Pro, asking for more and more personal info, and so on. I just need a nice, clean, and free way to remove networks that I've migrated from or dormant machines that just sit on my network.

Comment: Gotcha... We use LMIPro and Hamachi (paid) at work, so I guess I miss out on the fun.